# update granted on view, but cannot update underlying table, why?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table and a view. They are in different schema, but have the same owner:

- according to  sys.objects: principal_ID = null, schema_ID is 1 and 4
- according to sys.schemas: both schemas have the same principal_id (1 = dbo)

The view is simply `select a,b,c from table`

Now a user has been given the right to **select, insert, update and delete** rows from the view. He has no rights on the underlying table.

In fact, the user can select data. But if he wants to change anything, we get two errors: 'No SELECT granted on table" and "No UPDATE granted on table".

What is going wrong here?

Comment: There aren't any triggers on the view or the table are there?  As with the same owner for all the objects, this should work.

Comment: @steolary no, no triggers. I don't understand it. Due to ownership chaining, this should work. If I grant  update right to the table, then it works, but that spoils the whole idea of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that I was accessing the view with the C# `SqlCommandBuilder` class. But what I did not know is that the CommandBuilder tries to be "intelligent" and analyzes the view. It then creates statements which access the **underlying tables**, instead of the view. The only solution is to circumvent the SqlCommandBuilder.

I stumbled over the problem also this year, here is another link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31231563/2504785

Answer (score 2):

Update-able views are only update-able if you grant the permissions on the table, too:

> Requires UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE permissions on the target table, depending on the action being performed.

See the TechNet article [Modify Data Through a View](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180800.aspx).